# XPath query that respect node positon and attribute value

Tags: xpath, xpathdocument

Is there a way to build a XPath query that finds a node at a certain position AND with a certain attribute value?

Consider the following sample xml:

```
<Item Type="Book">
<!--1st Param node in a Book item is always the autors last name-->
<Param Value="Updike" />
<!--2nd Param node in a Book item is always the autors first name-->
<Param Value="John" />
<!--3rd Param node in a Book item is always the book title-->
<Param Value="Toward the End of Time" /></Item>
```

Now can I build a single query that finds the following:

Find all *Item* nodes of *Type* "Book" where the 2nd *Param* node has a *Value* of "John".
So I would like to find all books where the authors frist name is "John".

Note that I am using .NET XPathDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I am using .NET XPathDocument.

So limited to XPath V1.

You can include (relative and absolute) paths in a predicate. So something like:

```
//Item[@Type='Book'][./Param[2][@Value = 'John']]
```

(I would try and avoid "`//`", as it requires a search of the whole DOM, but can't provide a better axis without more context.)

Comment: Your expression is not limited to books.

Answer (score 5):

What about the requirement to have only the Item that are Books?

Try this:

```
/Item[@Type='Book'][Param[2][@Value='John']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression would be:

```
//Item/Param[2][@Value='John']
```